# in C# how to invoke base class method, which already override in derived class, from derived class instance

Tags: c#

I define two class, base class, person. and derived class customer.
in derived class, I re-write the display() method.
But I want to invoke base class(person)'s display method in customer instance.
how do I handle it?

I know in msdn, have some examples to invoke using `base()`, but my question is NOT invoke in class definition, but in instance invocation. I think it is different.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        person myperson = new person();
        myperson.DisplayInfo();

        customer mycustomer = new customer();
        mycustomer.DisplayInfo();

        //  --here I want to invoke person.display(). how to realize it?
        //mycustomer.base.DisplayInfo();
    }

    public class person
    {
        public string Name="base name";
        public virtual string DisplayInfo()
        {
            string msg = Name;
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            return msg;
        }
    }

    public class customer : person
    {
        public new void DisplayInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("derive "+ Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanted `new` not `override`?

Comment: avoid using `new` for `DisplayInfo`

Comment: "but I question is NOT invoke in class defination, but in instance invocation" --- what is the real problem you're solving with it? It sounds like a bad idea in the very first place.

Comment: This seems like a really _really_ bad design. What possible reason could you have for overriding a method in a derived class then expecting the _caller_ to know which one to call? You're moving knowledge of the implementation outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just use `new` to hide the base member, you can use

```
(mycustomer as person).DisplayInfo();
```

to call the base method, but I don't consider this good practice.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, this works, since the code uses new and not override

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov did so

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you override a base method you would still want to run the base method in your derived method

like:

```
public override void DisplayInfo()
{
     //call base method
     base.DisplayInfo();

     //add your extra code here
}
```

if you want to run your base method without running the derived logic 
it would be quite easy to add another method to your derived class to just call the base method you require

```
public void RunBaseDisplayInfo()
{
    base.DisplayInfo();
}
```

Comment: OP wants to make that on the caller side

Answer (score 0):

Your parent class can hold the instance of your child class.
Based on your example do this, it works.

```
    person mycustomer_in_person = new customer();
    mycustomer_in_person.DisplayInfo();
```